# Switch from bin/vendors to composer.phar : bug with annotation

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine-orm

```
AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\generatedValue" in property MyNamespace\UserBundle\Entity\User::$id does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

Here's my version of the composer.json : http://pastie.org/private/qredwfyytzl3ifhgqn7a

I didn't had the problem before when i was using old php bin/vendors update.

In the class i have :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
...

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\generatedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try with @ORM\GeneratedValue ?

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine annotations are key sensitive so use

> @ORM\GeneratedValue

instead of

> @ORM\generatedValue